# Display cards dynamically in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Heyy, it's the first time i use android studio and i want to display the content of a class in a card view dynamically on my page. For exemple I have a class Book that contains the Book title and a little description and i initialise 3 instances of books.. I want 3 cards in my page containing the books titles and description. How can this be done ? Thankz

[image]

Comment: do you want a single carview or a list of cardviews

Comment: @Achy97 a list of cardviews depending on a array of books lets say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a recycleview.

They are the steps }

First. Import the dependecy

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
}
```

Second. Add RecyclerView in xml

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Third. Create the adapter view

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp">
   <ImageView android:id="@+id/foto"
           android:layout_width="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
           android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
           android:contentDescription="fotografía"
           android:src="@drawable/bar"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>
   <TextView android:id="@+id/nombre"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Nombres del lugar"
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
           android:textStyle="bold"
           android:maxLines="1"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/foto"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
   <TextView android:id="@+id/direccion"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:maxLines="1"
           android:text="dirección del lugar"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/nombre"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/foto"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
   <RatingBar android:id="@+id/valoracion"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
           android:isIndicator="true"
           android:rating="3"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/direccion"
           app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/foto"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fourth. Create the adpater's class

```
class AdaptadorLugares(private val lugares: RepositorioLugares) :
                     RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorLugares.ViewHolder>() {

   class ViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

      fun personaliza(lugar: Lugar) = with(itemView){
         nombre.text = lugar.nombre
         direccion.text = lugar.direccion
         foto.setImageResource(when (lugar.tipoLugar) {
            TipoLugar.RESTAURANTE -> R.drawable.restaurante
            TipoLugar.BAR -> R.drawable.bar
            TipoLugar.COPAS -> R.drawable.copas
            TipoLugar.ESPECTACULO -> R.drawable.espectaculos
            TipoLugar.HOTEL -> R.drawable.hotel
            TipoLugar.COMPRAS -> R.drawable.compras
            TipoLugar.EDUCACION -> R.drawable.educacion
            TipoLugar.DEPORTE -> R.drawable.deporte
            TipoLugar.NATURALEZA -> R.drawable.naturaleza
            TipoLugar.GASOLINERA -> R.drawable.gasolinera
            TipoLugar.OTROS -> R.drawable.otros
         })
         foto.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_END)
         valoracion.rating = lugar.valoracion
      }
   }

   override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int):
                                                             ViewHolder {
      val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                          .inflate(R.layout.elemento_lista, parent, false)
      return ViewHolder(v)
   }

   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, posicion: Int) {
      val lugar = lugares.elemento(posicion)
      holder.personaliza(lugar)
   }

   override fun getItemCount() = lugares.tamanyo()
}
```

Finally call the adapter in activity's main

You can check the oficial documentation in google

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Example code

> http://www.androidcurso.com/index.php/691

Comment: Thanks for the hint, could you take a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62378352/recyclerview-layout-dont-match-the-screen-in-android-studio